# Server admin can't ftp in but anonymous can

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using server 2008 r2 and iis 7.5. We have a default ftp site configured and anonymouse users get in fine with read only access.

I can't get any domain users or even the domain admin in. I need to get in for write access.

I have gone into ftp authorization rules and have all users allowed for read, write permissions.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you add your anonymous user to the users which are allowed to access the ftp service?

Dos every user uses the anonymous under their own account?
If not, please try to use the local user to execute this program.

Comment: Right now we just go in as anonymous and all see the same files. Nobody can make any changes. When you try to log in with credentials, you get a "530 user cannot log in, home directory inaccessible" error.

Comment: ah ok, you need to create an account for accessing the FTP server. You can do this with windows user authent or just username and pw